# Adobe Lightroom 4.4.1 publishing to flickr

Tags: lightroom, flickr, publishing

When trying to publish photos to flickr.com I am getting the following error message `"Cant update this collection. An internal error occurred: a semicolon character was expected"`

I havent changed anything on my settings and recently it worked without any problem.
Is there any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a Flickr API problem that crops up periodically](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2004757?start=0&tstart=0). There's nothing you can do except wait for Yahoo (owner of Flickr) to fix the issue. It seems the fix usually only takes a few hours to a few days.

Other forums / info on the issue:

- [Suddenly Can't Upload from LR CC to Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157658718958342/) (flickr forums)
- [Lightroom: Can't update this collection: Semi Colon Expected](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/cant-update-this-collection-semi-colon-expected?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all&topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Breply_id%5D=16315423#reply_16315423) (photoshop.com)